# Asking a similar question

Tags: discussion

If a similar question exists, but asks from a different perspective, can I still ask a question (clarifying what I intend) or should I comment on the existing question?

Comment: Depends on the specific details. Quote the original question and your own. Tell us what site you intend to ask it on (different sites have different rules).

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: i wanted to ask on stackoverflow , something on bootstrap . i can find similar questions , but not the way answered as i need .

Comment: Comments are meant to be temporary. Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It depends.**

If you just need to know something straightforward, like "does this still work with version 2.7.4?" then you can comment on the answer asking that.

If you have determined that the answer, while correct for the time it was asked, doesn't apply now (especially with a new version) then it's best to ask a new question. Include a link to the old question and **explain what is different**. For example, "I have read [link to old question] but that is for an older version and the accepted answer to that question doesn't work for version 2.7.4." Never include vague phrases like "it doesn't discuss from my perspective."

I generally try to imagine the response I would get in order to choose what to do. If a person could easily edit their answer to include my concern, then I will probably comment. If answering my concern would require a whole different answer that wouldn't be useful to the original question, then it's clear I need to ask a different question. Linking to the old one saves everyone time and makes it less likely the question will be closed as a duplicate, if I do a good job of pre-explaining why it's not a duplicate, of course.

Comment: this gives the clarification , thanks